# Running an Excel Add-in function using VBA on remote desktop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have a scenario where we need to open a number of spreadsheets on a server, update a number of worksheets on each workbook by means of an add in button.

So the user opens remote desktop, opens a spreadsheet, goes to sheet x, goes to the add-ins menu and clicks a button.  This button updates the data on the sheet which takes several seconds.  Then they open sheet y and repeat.  Eventually all sheets are updated and the user saves and closes the sheet.

I am trying to automate this.  My thinking is to have a "master excel document" with a button to execute VBA code which will:

- Open a specific folder
- Open each workbook in the folder
- Cycle through the sheets and find the ones that need to be updated (as not every sheet needs to be updated)
- Once completed, save and close the sheet and then repeat for all workbooks and for all folders.

My major problem right now is that I need to figure out how to execute the Add-in function from my VBA code.  I have researched and found that I need to run it using code like this: APPLICATION.RUN "ADDIN_NAME.XLA!SUBNAME"

I think I have the ADDIN_NAME (found this by clicking file, options, add-ins).  But I cannot figure out how to get the subname.

Using the Macro recorder doesn't work - no code is recorded for clicking the add-in button.  When I hover my mouse over the add-in button, it give me "Analyst : Refresh Report, Use Current Criteria".  Any suggestions as to how I could work out what the subname is? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you not share the servers drive where the files are stored and just do it locally without RDP?

Comment: is the button in a ribbon or on the sheet?

Comment: @Tom, there are multiple permissions and services which the server has which are difficult/impossible to get locally.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the button is on the ribbon.

Comment: What is the addin? is it an `xla` file? Has it been developed in house or externally?

Comment: @Tom it was developed externally.  I will add some images of the add-in.

Comment: I hate to suggest this (because I don't like this method) but you could possibly use `Sendkeys` to emulate the keystrokes necessary to select the items from the menu.

Comment: does an approach like `Dim x As COMAddIn:Set x = Application.COMAddIns(y)` where y is the addin name yield any intelisense on the resultant object `x.object` for any publicly exposed functions of the addin.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could pry open the xls(m?) file by renaming it to zip, open it in ZIP, navigate to the customUI/customUI.xml and open that in Notepad. Reading that should give you the name of the macro each button added is calling.

eg.

```
 ....size="large" onAction="showuserform" imageMso="CreateRepo....
```

where `showuserform` is the name of the macro being called.

Comment: Ah yes, it's a VSTO. I believe you still write XML to manipulate the ribbon but probably tricky to read it once it's compiled (if that's the right word - I don't use VSTO myself)

Comment: Thanks CLR - I haven't managed to get anything that I could see as usable using this method.  I looked for various keywords to see if maybe one of the other files in there had something usable (outside of customUI.xml) but found nothing unfortunately.